# How to change the value of model field when button is clicked in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm making a django app in which the homepage shows list of internships available of different companies.A user of usertype=Student can view those internships. Each internship list view has a button named 'Apply' when apply is clicked I want the booleanfield in my django model(StudentApplying) named ***applied*** to be set to true. So that the company who created this post can view the list of students who applied  and then can accept/reject them. I don't want to use ajax,javascript etc unless there is no way I can't do it with django itself.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from InternsOnboardMain.models import internshipPost
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class StudentApplying(models.Model):
    companyName = 
models.ForeignKey(internshipPost,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    studentName = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    applied = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**view.py**(*I've tried this but it is not working*)

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect,get_object_or_404
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import StudentApplying
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import F

def applyStatus(request):
    if request.GET.get('applybtn'):
        profil = get_object_or_404(StudentApplying, 
        created_by=request.user)
        profil.applied = True
        profil.save(update_fields=["applied"])
        return redirect('InternsOnboard-Home')
    return HttpResponse('Not done')
```

**I have not used any forms.py**

**html file**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'Student-Apply' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<button class="btn btn-info" name="applybtn">Apply</button>
</form>
```

**There is no necessity to have  tags**

Comment: Hi @Kiran, I do not have too much time at the moment for a full checking but in your code this line looks wrong first of all: `if request.GET.get('applybtn'):` - since the request is POST when you submit a Form, so you should use: `if request.POST.get('applybtn'):`

Comment: @Zollie thank you for responding so quick, but even after changing to POST it doesn't work. It returns "Not done" either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking this a little more, the problem looks like that you try to submit an empty form. So you should try to do the following:

in the view:

```
if “applybtn” in request.POST:
    # do this and that
```

The name of the button will be in the request thus it should work.